# Android studio .AAB build failing due to "other has a different root"

Tags: android, android-manifest

So, I have made a app with two activities. 1st one has a simple login screen without firebase, and another activity has a webview and adview.
So this error shows up evreytime.

```
> Task :app:produceReleaseBundleIdeListingFile FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:produceReleaseBundleIdeListingFile'.
> 'other' has different root

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

When I built the .apk, it worked on my android device perfectly, but when I build a signed .AAB to publish to the google play console, the error kept on showing up. So heres the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CLS2RLibraryApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.cls2r.library.MainActivit2y" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-4019846687800073~3281435460"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: EDIT: The problem has been fixed.
Looks like it does not like to build to another drive letter. i.e. Key store path is on D: and destination folder on E: and I get the message 'other' has different root. Note that the file seems to be produced on E: anyway. When I change destination folder to D: it's all ok.